# 'error NG6002: XY does not appear to be an NgModule class' although it clearly is one

Tags: angular

When trying to build an application, I got this error:

```
error NG6002: 'DemoPagesModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

23         DemoPagesModule
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  demo/src/app/pages/demo-pages.module.ts:74:14
    74 export class DemoPagesModule {}
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?
```

It is particular puzzling, as it is asking me whether it is missing an @NgModule annotation annotation, although the imported module clearly has one.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the error was deceiving, nothing was wrong about the imported module and its annotation. It turned out there was an issue with one of the `imports` of the module. Angular's builder did **not** throw an error about this but moved on as if there was no error and this module just did not exist.